# Can't a Reader read *directly* from a StringBuilder?

Tags: java, java-io

I'm using an API that requires a [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) to read from, and this `Reader` should actually read from a (potentially very large) [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

But using this:

```
new StringReader(stringBuilder.toString());
```

...will copy the internal `StringBuilder`'s `char` array, which I want to avoid due to array size.
Although, this `char` array is package-protected.

And no better luck with [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) :(

Am I missing something?

*Note: I can't use Java 7 at this time.*

Comment: You could make your own subclass that inherits from Reader (or StringReader); apparently it's pretty easy.

Comment: A `Reader` reads sequentially, a `StringBuilder/Buffer` can be changed randomly. How should this work without creating a `String`/copying the array in this system? If you only `append` to the `Builder/Buffer` you could construct a better producer than a `StringBuilder/Buffer` for the reader.

Comment: @his: You're right. But in my case, I didn't have the choice on  StringBuilder... I will try 'n3k0' or 'ChrisMartin' ideas for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StringBuilder` implements `CharSequence`, so you can use [`CharSequenceReader`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CharSequenceReader.html) from Apache `commons-io`.

Comment: [Guava now offers a `CharSequenceReader`, too](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/io/CharSequenceReader.java)